# Tiny tower re stocking

Tags: tiny-tower

I was wondering if you could help me with Tiny Tower. I was just checking up and went to the floor that were restocking when I saw the a green line was going through the page on the bar that shows you how far it is to being done, also it says that it will take 2 days to restock!

I have no idea what is wrong please help or tell me if it will be fine in 2 days.

I have recently lost 2 Bitizens through time travelling accidents, is this because I was changing the date/time?

Comment: Thank you so much, I wasn't even changing it for that game :3 oh well, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the game now (for the past year or so) punishes you for time traveling (playing with date/time at all). The stock should actually be restored in 2 days time though,  the game clock "plays" in the background so  it's not like you need to leave the game open for 2 days or anything.

Comment: possible source of your information? http://tinytower.wikia.com/wiki/Bux ?

Comment: (notes section of the page.)